# Curl query to C# code

Tags: c#, curl

I have got (probably simple for you) question.

I would like to 'convert' curl query to a C# `HttpClient` request.

My curl query is :

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
     -H "X-Cookie: mycookie" 
     -F "Filename=myfilename" -F "Filedata=@filepath" http://website...
```

Could you be so kind and help me ?

I tried to code :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Cookie", string.Format("token={0}", token));

        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("Compliance"), "Filename");
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)), "Filedata", "Compliance");

        // Add a new Request Message
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, yourUrl);

        // Add our custom headers
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Cookie", string.Format("token={0}", token));
        requestMessage.Content = multipartFormDataContent;
        requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

        // Send the request to the server
        var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result; 
    }
}
```

I also tried this code :

```
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                  postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Filename", "myfilename"));
                  postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Filedata", filepath));
                  HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mywebsite");
                  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Cookie", string.Format("token={0}", token));
                  var a = httpClient.PostAsync("/file/upload", content).Result;
```

But I am receiveing "Unknown error", I do not know how to do this...

I do not know how to inform request about : "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" ?

I tried in another way :

```
 string input = "Filename=myfilename&Filedata=@" + filepath;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yourUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Cookie", string.Format("token={0}", token));

        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        request.ContentLength = input.Length;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        newStream.Flush();

        var response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var stream = response3.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string result3 = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I received and error :

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

====

Could you be so kind and advise me what should I correct in my code or maybe you can show me how should I do this ?

Comment: OK, so you have coded it - and? Are you getting errors? Just no response? What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I am receiveing this error :     response2 = {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Unknown Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 21:44:37 GMT
  Content-Length: 37
  Content-Typ...